# I am not able to edit my products in backend

Tags: magento

I am not able to edit my products in backend. it is giving error as Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons. I also check the report:

> Source model "tpl_eventsmanager/event_source" not found for attribute "events"

```html
Trace:
#0 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "t...')
#1 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#2 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Attributes.php(70): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Array)
#3 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#4 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php(79): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#7 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#8 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'product_tabs')
#9 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'product_tabs')
#10 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#11 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#12 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#13 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#14 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(Array, true, true)
#15 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(250): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout(Array)
#16 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->editAction()
#17 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#18 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /home/dme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /home/dme/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/dme/public_html/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

Tried fixing it by replacing null to tmp/ in file.php but still nothing seems to work. I am going wrong somewhere.

Comment: do you have any attribute with code "events" in backend ?

Comment: yes i have events attribute

Comment: the visibility is no and when i made it yes the error is coming on the front end saying Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Comment: Hey, i deleted events attribute and backend is working thank you so much to get me to the point. now the issue is my product images are not loading in the fronend. its just a a circular progress bar keeps rotating.

Comment: good to hear that, i am going to post an answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @NS123 Did you found solution, if so please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its related to the attribute "events" in backend.

once you delete the attribute , it will work for you.